# How to get an array of values from a conditional ActiveRecord query with associations?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to define a method on one of my objects that will return a just one column of data from all of its child objects so long as another column in the same record meets certain conditions.

For instance if I have two objects

```
ParentObject
  has_many: child_objects

  #fields
  name (string)

ChildObject
  belongs_to: parent_object

  #fields
  name (string)
  whitelisted_at (datetime)
```

I've read up that I can get a list of all child_object records for a parent_object based on a conditional specified using .where(). For instance in my controller I have code like so:

```
ParentObject.child_objects.where("whitelisted_at IS NOT NULL")
```

This gives me an active record associate like so:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [
<ChildObject id: 1, name:"Susan", whitelisted_at: "2015-02-18 12:07:37">,
<ChildObject id: 1, name:"Simon", whitelisted_at: "2015-02-18 12:07:37">, 
<ChildObject id: 1, name:"Sally", whitelisted_at: "2015-02-18 12:07:37">
]
```

I was looking how I would then filter through these to return an array of just names. Ideally i'd be able to run this all as a Model method so:

```
class ChainObject < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  def whitelisted_names
    #... outputs [Susan, Simon, Sally]
  end
end
```

What would be the most concise and rails-y way of doing this. I thought about doing a .where() then an .each() and having a block method but that seems really cumbersome and I'm sure I'm just missing some smart ActiveRecord or Association method that could pluck an array of values from multiple hashes. I'm pouring over the APIdock but I think the problem is I don't know how to describe what I'm trying to do!

Comment: There's a `pluck` method, I thought it worked with conditionals as well, but may be wrong; haven't used Rails in awhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your parent model you could use [`where.not`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions) and use the pluck method ActiveRecord gives you (props to Stefan - see [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck))

```
class ParentObject < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  def whitelisted_names
    child_objects.where.not(whitelisted_at: nil).pluck(:name)
  end
end
```

Comment: self.child_objects.where.not(whitelisted_at: nil).map(&:name) appears to work... That's awesome thank you so much. Humm .map() eh? I guess I should go read up on that. Could you explain what the & is doing in that final method? Also is there any advantage to using .where.not() instead of .where("whitelisted_at IS NOT NULL") ?

Comment: I think where.not is more idiomatic and easier to read but that's a style thing, they both do the same thing.  Added info for the map with proc method.

Comment: Ah, Proc, yet another on the newbie to-learn list. Thanks for all the help I'll mark this as answered when the timelock expires!

Comment: Or: `child_objects.where.not(whitelisted_at: nil).pluck(:name)`